# OAuth Authorization in Golang CLI Applications

Tags: go, browser, oauth-2.0, oauth

I've been using the code from the [OAuth2 package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2#example-Config) to add authorization to my CLI application, but I've run into a bit of a snag.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    conf := &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
        ClientSecret: "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
        Scopes:       []string{"SCOPE1", "SCOPE2"},
        Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
            AuthURL:  "https://provider.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            TokenURL: "https://provider.com/o/oauth2/token",
        },
    }

    // Redirect user to consent page to ask for permission
    // for the scopes specified above.
    url := conf.AuthCodeURL("state", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    fmt.Printf("Visit the URL for the auth dialog: %v", url)

    // Use the authorization code that is pushed to the redirect
    // URL. Exchange will do the handshake to retrieve the
    // initial access token. The HTTP Client returned by
    // conf.Client will refresh the token as necessary.
    var code string
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&code); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tok, err := conf.Exchange(ctx, code)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client := conf.Client(ctx, tok)
    client.Get("...")
}
```

I'm using StackOverflow as the authorization server and [api.stackexchange.com doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) says the following. But I'm not sure what it means.

> Desktop applications cannot participate directly in OAuth 2.0 flows, however the embeddable browser controls available in most frameworks make it possible to work around this limitation.

The issue is that when I use the method described in the documentation, I have to manually click the URL generated in the CLI and manually copy the access token to continue.

Do you happen to know of a way to automate these two steps in Golang or a different approach I could take for authorization in CLI applications?

What I'm hoping for is something like what you see in the `heroku-cli` but with OAuth 2.0 - it would be awesome if my app could handle authorization in a similar way. Thanks for your help!

I'd really appreciate any help or advice you can offer. Thanks!

Comment: I did something like this years ago, so ymmv: https://github.com/bserdar/took/blob/master/proto/oidc/htmlform.go

Answer (score 0):

When you make an authorization request to your provider (see [RFC6479 section 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1)), one of the request parameters is a `redirect_uri`. From the spec there:

> The client constructs the request URI by adding the following
> parameters to the query component of the authorization endpoint URI
> using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format, per Appendix B:
>
> - response_type -
>   REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "code".
> - client_id -
>   REQUIRED.  The client identifier as described in Section 2.2.
> - redirect_uri -
>   OPTIONAL.  As described in Section 3.1.2.
> - scope -
>   OPTIONAL.  The scope of the access request as described by
>   Section 3.3.
> - state -
>   RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
>   state between the request and callback.  The authorization
>   server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
>   to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
>   cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.

In `golang.org/x/oauth2` the `redirect_uri` is exposed in the `oauth2.Config` struct as [RedirectURL](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.RedirectURL). The authorization flow involves the user logging in through a browser. When that flow completes, the user is redirected back to this `RedirectURL`. The parameters passed back to this URL are defined by [RFC6479 section 4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2):

> If the resource owner grants the access request, the authorization
> server issues an authorization code and delivers it to the client by
> adding the following parameters to the query component of the
> redirection URI using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format,
> per Appendix B:
>
> - code -
>   REQUIRED.  The authorization code generated by the
>   authorization server.  The authorization code MUST expire
>   shortly after it is issued to mitigate the risk of leaks.  A
>   maximum authorization code lifetime of 10 minutes is
>   RECOMMENDED.  The client MUST NOT use the authorization code
>   more than once.  If an authorization code is used more than
>   once, the authorization server MUST deny the request and SHOULD
>   revoke (when possible) all tokens previously issued based on
>   that authorization code.  The authorization code is bound to
>   the client identifier and redirection URI.
> - state -
>   REQUIRED if the "state" parameter was present in the client
>   authorization request.  The exact value received from the
>   client.

Your CLI app should implement a localhost webserver with a handler that can receive this authorization response. Typically, it would be something like http://localhost:PORT/redirect. You'll typically find that this redirect URL has to be registered on your authorization provider, so that the provider will allow the use of this callback. Best practice is to specify the `state` in the request and ensure that you receive the same `state` value in your authorization response handler.

To initiate the process, you can use something like [github.com/skratchdot/open-golang/open.Run](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/skratchdot/open-golang/open#Run) to open the browser window with the authorization request URI from 4.1.1 - that will allow the user to login and redirect back to your handler for the response.  Your http handler can then extract the code received.